# What is the history of the FICS mutual game history command>

Tags: history, online-chess

On FICS, I remember there was a command to see your mutual game history with a given user. But I can't find it now. Can you name it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
hstat /o <opponent>
```

Please see [this page](http://www.freechess.org/Help/HelpFiles/hstat.html) for detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a regular FICS user. I just google this up. See if it helps. 
[FAQ](http://www.freechess.org/Help/ficsfaq.html)

> Type history to see your last 10 games. The letters l, b, s indicate lightning, 
>   blitz, standard and the letters u and r indicate unrated and rated.

If nothing helps, this should: 
[FICS support/contact page](http://www.freechess.org/contact.html)